# Como fazer previsão de valores futuros de uma série temporal?

Tags: matlab, regressão

Eu tenho valores de uma série temporal com uma amostragem de 5 em 5 minutos. Como posso prever valores futuros usando apenas essa informação? Como posso modelar algo num período de tempo e usar para prever no futuro (estou a tentar prever o valor da glucose numa pessoa)? Como prever os valores se por acaso a frequência de amostragem não for constante?

Dado que ainda não sou muito entendido na matéria, uns tutoriais seriam bem vindos junto com as vossas possíveis explicações.

PS: Necessito primeiro de entender na teoria para depois perceber na prática ;)

Answer (score 0):

Eu não sou a pessoa certa para dar esta resposta...

Ainda assim aí vai um arranque simplicista:

- associado a uma previsão de valores futuros existe normalmente a escolha de um "modelo"
  do comportamento esperado dos dados (ex. modelo linear, polinomial, frame, splines). Esse modelo tem a ver
  com o enredo concreto, e por vezes pode ser "adivinhado" com base nos dados existentes.
- com base no modelo e nos dados existentes, consegue-se determinar as constantes da função modelo; e com base nesta determinar o valor esperado para um instante futuro e respectiva confiança.

Sugiro que comeces por algum texto ligado a:

- Machine Learning; séries temporais;
- É habitual recorrer-se a linguagens ligadas à estatística (Exemplo R) que
  contêm algumas bibliotecas ligadas a prediction.
  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/predict.lm.html

Comment: Eu tenho conhecimentos a nível de machine learning mas para problemas de classificação. @JJoao, conhece algum documento que explique bastante bem as séries temporais? Tenho vindo a ler coisas relacionadas com esse assunto mas está um pouco difícil de entender :(

Comment: Não sou a pessoa certa... Sugeria que espreitasses na khan.academy um pouco de estatistica e "time series", que visitasses o cursera ou por exemplo http://ocw.metu.edu.tr/course/view.php?id=145. Talvez um livro à moda antiga!

Comment: Um dos melhores livros "à moda antiga": http://www.amazon.com/Pattern-Classification-2nd-Computer-Manual/dp/0471703508/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1439468395&sr=1-1&keywords=pattern+classification+duda  :)

Comment: Outra opção mais focada: http://www.amazon.com/Time-Analysis-James-Douglas-Hamilton/dp/0691042896/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1439468528&sr=1-2&keywords=time+series

Answer (score 0):

O ponto crítico para prever é calcular a autocorrelação da série. Isso é como os valores passados influenciam na determinação de valores futuros. Depois tem que analisar se essa relação é linear, nesse caso tem muitas opções de modelagem de séries temporais utilizando modelos de regressão.

Várias outras informações e links podem ser encontradas nessa questão [similar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67566/18681)

Um Exemplo com dados simulados é mostrado a seguir

```
%# Gerar uma variável aleatória autocorrelacionada em 3 períodos.
T = 1000;
%
RV = zeros(T, 1); RV(1)=10+randn(1); RV(2)=1.5+.8*RV(1)+randn(1);
RV(3)=1.5+.8*RV(1)-.3*RV(1)+randn(1);
for c = 4:T ; RV(c)=1.5+.8*RV(c-1)-.3*RV(c-2)+.25*RV(c-3)+randn(1); end

% Pode iniciar aqui fazendo RV = SuaVariavel

plot(RV)

%# Construindo as variaveis com 3 defasagens
yout = RV(4:end); %# dependente
X1 = RV(3:end-1); %# defasagens da dependente (1er regressor)
X2 = RV(2:end-2);
X3 = RV(1:end-3);
%# matriz de regressores incluindo constante
X_train = [ones(length(X1), 1), X1, X2, X3];

%# MQO
mdl = regress(yout, X_train);
mdl

# Prever
X_test = [1, RV(T-1), RV(T-2), RV(T-3)];
%pred = predict(mdl,X_test);
sum(mdl'.*X_test) ; % Y em T+1
```