# Como fazer Multiple Linear Regression?

Tags: matlab, regressão

-- Pergunta reformulada --

Eu tenho o seguinte código

```
mdl = LinearModel.fit(X_train,y_train);
pred = predict(mdl,X_test);
```

em que `X_train` é uma matriz [m x n] com `m` exemplos e `n` features (valores passados da time series). `y_train` é um vector coluna com a resposta (valores no instante seguinte). **De notar que a minha time series é do tipo univariate,** ou seja, só tenho o registo de uma variável ao longo do tempo.

Questões:

1. Isto está correcto? Pela resposta do Luiz, está.
2. O `y_train` pode conter o valor do sinal P passos à frente? Ex: f(t+p)
3. Podem-me explicar o output do modelo?
4. A função linear é aproximada com recurso ao método dos mínimos quadrados, certo?
5. Existirá alguma razão para que este método dê melhores resultados quando comparado com o algoritmo SVR tanto com o kernel linear como o RBF?

EDIT1:

```
clc; close all;
clear all;

T = 20;


% Pode inicial aqui fazendo RV = SuaVariavel
RV = 1:T;
RV = RV';

%plot(RV)

%# Construindo as variaveis com 3 defasagens

N = 3;
first = 1;
for i=N:-1:1
    if first == 1
        X = RV(i:end+(i-1)-N);
        first = 0;
    else
        X = horzcat(X,RV(i:end+(i-1)-N) );
    end
end

HP = 1; % <-----------------------------------------------------

X = horzcat(ones(length(X),1),X);
y = RV(N+HP:end,end);

lim = length(X);

X_train = X(round(1:lim*0.7),:);
y_train = y(round(1:lim*0.7));

X_test = X(round(lim*0.7+0.5):end-(HP-1),:);
y_test = y(round(lim*0.7+0.5):end);


%# MQO
mdl = regress(y_train, X_train);
mdl


% Prever
for i=1:length(X_test)

    pred(i)=sum(mdl'.*X_test(i,:)); 

end


figure()
hold on;
plot(pred,'r*-')
plot(y_test,'go-')
hold off
```

EDIT 2:
Neste [link](http://www.filedropper.com/corrpacf) está uma imagem com o gráfico de autocorrelacção (cima) e o PACF (baixo). As minhas conclusões são que ele evidência que um modelo AR funciona dado que o valor de autocorrelacção vai baixando lentamente à medida que o valor do lag aumenta. Para além disso, o máximo de lag que se poderá considerar é 6. O que acontece se considerar-mos mais? Simplesmente as previsões no futuro não serão tão certas (poderão conter mais ruído devido à inclusão de mais instantes passados) ?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo(a) ao SOPT. Sem querer parecer grosseiro, mas você já olhou [a documentação do Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multiple-linear-regression-1.html)? Lá tem um bom número de exemplos. A sua pergunta tem mais chances de ser respondida se você torná-la mais focada e objetiva. Procure postar o que já tentou (inclusive o código de um exemplo mínimo, se o tiver) e foque na sua dificuldade específica, incluindo particularmente detalhes do domínio de problema que deseja solucionar.

Comment: Olá. Eu já ainda a ler algumas coisas mas dado que para ser honesto não percebo nada de regressão ainda não consegui escrever nenhum código pelo que qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Comment: Entendo. Mas a questão é que o SOPT não é um fórum, e sim um site de perguntas e respostas *objetivas* (já fez o [tour]?). Se você tem dificuldades com a matemática, eu sugiro estudá-la antes de iniciar o aprendizado com o Matlab. Dá uma olhada nos exemplos, tenta resolver algo simples e ir aumentando a complexidade. E quando você tiver alguma dúvida específica (exemplo: o que faz tal comando? por que a resposta desse código é essa?, etc), venha aqui e poste a pergunta (você pode postar mais de uma pergunta). Do jeito que a pergunta está hoje, está  ampla demais para ter respostas objetivas.

Comment: Ah, é importante lembrar que o Matlab está no escopo do site, mas a matemática sozinha não. O SOPT é voltado à programação. Se você tiver facilidade com inglês e quiser postar uma pergunta apenas sobre a matemática, sugiro outro site do grupo StackExchange, o [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Bem ... na pesquisa sobre este assunto encontrei o método LinearModel.fit(X,y) que cria um modelo linear, certo? O meu X é uma matriz [m x n] em que m é o número de exemplos e n é o número de valores passados (t-n),(t-n+1),...,(t) e y é um vector coluna [m x 1]. Será que posso fazer isto?

mdl = LinearModel.fit(X_train,y_train);
y_pred = predict(mdl,X_test);

Mais uma questão: os valores que passo no y_train são os do instante seguinte (t+1). Posso passar outros instantes, por exemplo, (t+4) e quando faço o predict obtenho a previsão 4 instantes no futuro? Espero que me consiga entender.

Comment: 1) Sim pode. 2) Os valors de `y_train` DEVEM ser as classes/resultados reais dos dados de treinamento, e não do que você quer prever 3) Pode, desde que tenha o vetor do exemplo daquele momento no futuro. -- Por isso que eu disse, **edite** a sua pergunta pra deixar ela mais específica a respeito da sua dúvida e forneça exemplos dos seus dados/código. Leituras que *podem* ser úteis: [leitura 1](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40135/explicar-o-algoritmo-svr) e [leitura 2](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66777/d%C3%BAvidas-na-utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-stratified-k-fold-no-scikit-learn).

Comment: @LuizVieira, desde já obrigado pela sua ajuda. Já editei a pergunta e acrescentei mais umas dúvidas :)

Comment: O que esta tentando fazer é um modelo autorregressivo, onde defasagens da própria variável são utilizadas como explicativas dos valores futuros. Não tenho matlab instalado neste pc, mas olhe no manual http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/autoregressive-model.html?searchHighlight=Autoregressive%20Modeling

Comment: @Robert, já andava a ver esse método no entanto está um pouco difícil de implementar por causa dos parâmetros. Segundo a documentação `m = ar(y,na)`. `y` são os valores da time series e `na` é quantos instantes passados (digamos N ) queremos considerar ( t-N, t-N+1, ..., t ) certo? Como posso fazer previsões com este modelo? Vou continuar a procurar mas se puder dar um exemplo agradeço-lhe :)

Comment: HP tem que ser usada também para atualizar a matriz X, se não, ao alterar esse valor para 2 (ou 3) vai estar relacionando erradamente as defasagens, por exemplo, y4 com com y2 e inferiores, desconsiderando y3.

Comment: @Robert Isso seria a ideia ... ter por exemplo o seguinte caso [1 3 2 1] em que (3,2,1) são os instantes passado e a saída ser 5 ou 6 ou até mais. Por outras palavras iria estar a prever directamente 2 instantes (para o caso da saída ser igual a 5) directamente no futuro em vez de prever o 4 e só depois o 5. O que quero fazer é multi-step ahead prediction (HP >=2) mas também experimentar o one-step ahead prediction (HP = 1). Que acha? Não é mesmo possível?

Comment: Para determinar a ordem das defasagens olhe a função de autocorrelação. Se não existir autocorrelação sua previsão poderá ser muito pobre.

Comment: @Robert, por favor veja o Edit 2. No entanto continuo com a mesma dúvida que tinha quando escrevi o comentário anterior. Será que dá para explicar melhor?

Answer (score 2):

Como você não forneceu dados de exemplo do seu domínio de problema (apesar de eu ter pedido duas vezes), eu tive que usar alguma fonte de dados publicamente disponível na Internet. Optei por usar os dados da população de coelhos no deserto de Chihuahuan (na fronteira entre os EUA e o México) entre os anos de 1989 e 1994. Esses dados estão publicamente disponíveis [aqui](http://jornada-www.nmsu.edu/studies/lter/datasets/animals/anmltran/anmltran.dat), e sua documentação pode ser acessada [aqui](http://jornada-www.nmsu.edu/studies/lter/datasets/animals/anmltran/anmltran.dsd).

> **Observação**: Essa fonte de dados na verdade contém os valores
>   populacionais de diferentes animais (pássaros, coelhos, lagartos,
>   etc) coletados em diferentes dias. Para construir o exemplo eu tive que
>   importar o arquivo DAT no Excel e filtrar dele apenas os dados de coelhos. Fiz
>   também a soma das contagens por ano, para ter como resultado a tabela a seguir:
>
> ```
> Ano   Número de Coelhos
> 1989  32
> 1990  98
> 1991  90
> 1992  91
> 1993  105
> 1994  134
> ```

Então, preparei o exemplo de código em Matlab a seguir para ilustrar as explicações.

```
% Exemplo de dados de treinamento
x = [1989 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994] % Ano de medição
y = [32 98 90 91 105 134]           % Número de coelhos no ano

% Plota o gráfico de dispersão (em uma janela com 80% do tamanho da tela)
screen = get(groot,'ScreenSize');
w = 0.8 * screen(3)
h = 0.8 * screen(4)
figure('OuterPosition', [screen(3)/2-w/2 screen(4)/2-h/2 w h], 'Name', 'Gráfico Ilustrativo - SOPT', 'NumberTitle', 'off')

hold on
scatter(x, y, 240, 'k', 's', 'filled')
axis([1988 1996 0 180])

title('\fontsize{25}Crescimento Populacional de Coelhos no Deserto de Chihuahuan (EUA/México)')
xlabel('\fontsize{16}Ano')
ylabel('\fontsize{16}Número de Coelhos')

% Adiciona ao gráfico as curvas de tendência linear (vermelho) e quadrática (verde)
fit_linear = polyfit(x, y, 1);
x2 = 1989:1994
y2 = polyval(fit_linear, x2)

fit_quad = polyfit(x(2:end), y(2:end), 2); % NOTA: Primeira medida intencionalmente ignorada (possível outlier?)
x3 = 1990:1994                             % Aqui também!
y3 = polyval(fit_quad, x3)

plot(x2, y2, 'b--o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'b')
plot(x3, y3, 'r--o', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'r')

% Faz previsões para o ano 1995 e plota no gráfico
ano = 1995
prev_linear = polyval(fit_linear, ano)
prev_quad = polyval(fit_quad, ano)

plot(ano, prev_linear, 'b*', 'MarkerSize', 22)
plot(ano, prev_quad, 'r+', 'MarkerSize', 22)

legend('Dados Originais', 'Tendência Linear', 'Tendência Quadrática (ignorando primeira medição/possível outlier)', 'Previsão (Linear) para 2000', 'Previsão (Quadrática) para 2000', 'Location', 'northwest')
```

Esse código gera o seguinte gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perceba no código o seguinte trecho:

```
fit_linear = polyfit(x, y, 1);
x2 = 1989:1994
y2 = polyval(fit_linear, x2)

fit_quad = polyfit(x(2:end), y(2:end), 2); % NOTA: Primeira medida intencionalmente ignorada (possível outlier?)
x3 = 1990:1994                             % Aqui também!
y3 = polyval(fit_quad, x3)
```

O que ocorre ali são justamente duas regressões, uma linear e uma não-linear (usando uma função quadrática como base). A função `polyfit` cria um *modelo* para os dados de treinamento (valores de `x` e `y`) usando um polinômio com o grau dado no terceiro parâmetro (1 para linear, 2 para quadrático, 3 para cúbico, etc). E a função `polyval` usa esse *modelo* para estimar um ou mais novos valores. Nesse trecho do código, o segundo parâmetro nas duas chamadas (`x2` ou `x3`) são vetores, então ele vai estimar um resultado para cada valor desse vetor, por isso resultando também em um vetor (de estimativas). Mais pra baixo eu adiciono no gráfico uma estimativa para o ano de 1995, e você verá que o valor passado é um escalar (um único valor, ao invés de um vetor). Nesse caso, a função também retorna um único escalar.

O tal "modelo" nada mais é do que uma função "extraída" a partir dos dados de treinamento. Considere o exemplo da regressão linear. A ideia é tentar "inferir" uma função que, dado as variáveis que caracterizam o "problema" (nesse exemplo ilustrativo, apenas o ano - valor `x`), calcula o resultado com base nessa variável (nesse exemplo, o número de coelhos - valor `y`). Não vou entrar em detalhes da matemática *porque esse não é o foco do SOPT*, mas uma forma de fazer isso é como você mencionou: os fatores `a` e `b` da equação liniear na forma `ax+b` são estimados a partir da redução do erro quadrático entre o ponto original (nos dados de treinamento) e o ponto calculado pela função (o valor "estimado"). Assim, a melhor equação é aquela em que a distância entre os pontos (no gráfico mesmo - é só comparar os pontos originais em preto com os pontos da função, em azul na linear e vermelho na quadrática), acumulada, é a menor possível.

Se você testar os dados da tabela acima em um site de regressão linear online [como este, por exemplo](http://www.alcula.com/calculators/statistics/linear-regression/), vai perceber que o resultado (o tal "modelo") nada mais é do que uma função. Nesse exemplo, a função linear resultante é:

```
y = 15.2 x - 30179.133333333
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde `x` é o ano (a variável, característica ou *feature* de um exemplo no domínio de problema) e `y` é o número de coelhos (o valor estimado desejado).

Note que na segunda regressão, não linear, o valor da primeira medição (número de coelhos no ano 1989) foi intencionalmente ignorado porque olhando o gráfico ele parece ser um "ponto fora da curva" literalmente (um *outlier*). Talvez seja um erro de medição... ou talvez não. Eu não sei porque não conheço em detalhes o domínio do problema e porque o número de dados (6 exemplos) é muito pequeno para uma decisão mais acertada. Esse é o tipo de análise que **você** precisa fazer ao desenvolver a sua solução. Plotar os dados em um gráfico e analisar as tendências é uma ótima forma de fazê-lo.

Isso é muito importante porque a escolha muda completamente o resultado da estimação, como você vai perceber nos valores do gráfico estimados para o ano de 1995 (que variam bastante conforme a escolha pelo modelo linear ou pelo modelo quadrático ignorando o primeiro exemplo).

Para encerrar, há outros detalhes importantes. Primeiramente, esse é um exemplo meramente *ilustrativo*. Dificilmente há alguma correlação entre o ano e o número de coelhos no deserto. É natural que o número deles cresça ao longo do tempo (e por isso, o modelo linear pode parecer o mais correto). Mas, as vezes o número desses animais tem baixas devido a escassez de alimento (o que pode ter ocorrido ali entre 1991 e 1992, justificando esses dados casarem melhor com um modelo quadrático) e isso provavelmente seja mais bem explicado por outras variáveis. De fato, talvez o problema seja realmente linear com uma variável mais apropriada.

Além disso, pra facilitar a minha vida (e pra tornar mais didático) eu usei apenas uma variável nesse modelo (o valor de `x` como sendo o ano). O seu problema pode ser mais complexo do que isso, e requerer mais do que uma variável (isto é, precisar ser representado por uma equação do tipo `g = x^2 + y^2 + z^2`, com três variáveis `x`, `y`, e `z`). Se você tiver um problema com duas variáveis, o seu gráfico já passa a ser tridimensional (porque vai ter um eixo para cada variável e um para o resultado), e a "curva" deixa de ser uma linha para ser um plano. Com mais variáveis, essa dimensão cresce e já nem dá pra visualizar facilmente (você vai precisar construir visualizações para cada par de variáveis - como ilustrado [no Iris Dataset, na Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set)). Mas o princípio da coisa é o mesmo: só no código o seu vetor de entrada (o `x`) vai deixar de ser um vetor para ser uma matriz, como você mesmo menciona, com uma coluna para cada variável de interesse.

A classe que você está usando (`LinearModel`) é mais apropriada para a regressão multivariável, e provavelmente é por isso que você a está utilizando. A função `fit` faz a construção do modelo (isto é, "aprende" a função a partir dos dados) e a função `predict` usa esse modelo para estimar um novo resultado a partir de novas entradas. É por isso que você não pode confundir os dados (`y_train` tem os resultados para os dados que você tem, e que vai usar para construir o modelo).

Sobre usar outros algoritmos, tome alguns cuidados. O SVR é uma regressão construída a partir do algoritmo SVM (se ainda não viu, [veja esta minha outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40149/73)). Só que esse algoritmo foi originalmente construído com a intenção de servir como um *classificador* (ou seja, ao invés de prever um valor como resultado de uma função para a aplicação de novos dados de exemplo, ele indica a qual classe dentre duas possíveis pertence o exemplo caracterizado por aqueles dados). Como eu explico lá na outra resposta, o SVR usa múltiplos testes para estimar, por meio de probabilidades, um valor de regressão. Nesse caso, é mais prático (e tem melhor desempenho) se você usar algoritmos de regressão diretamente.

Comment: Obrigado desde já pela sua resposta bastante completa. No entanto, como disse os meus dados são de uma time series univariável, ou seja, tenho valores com um intervalo fixo. Usei a classe `LinearModel` pois construí o meu dataset de forma a que cada exemplo tivesse `N` valores passados e ainda o valor actual. Ex: N=3

1 | 2 | 3 | 4   ->  5 (valor de saída)

X = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5]

Agora as questões que ainda não consegui perceber:

1. O valor de y pode ser por exemplo 6 (ou seja, seria a saída 2 instantes depois do actual e quando prevemos X obtemos uma previsão para esse instante) ?

Comment: A questão é que no seu exemplo você tenta prever a população de coelhos em função do ano e o meu problema é do género prever a população de coelhos tendo em conta o historial da população de coelhos.

Comment: Por univariável vc quer dizer que tem só uma variável? Qual é ela? Quando eu mencionei que você não explicou o seu domínio é porque você não explicou mesmo. O que esses números representam? Se eu soubesse o que são talvez ficasse mais fácil de ajudar. O valor de `y` não pode ser 6, porque não é a resposta correta para os dados `[1, 2, 3, 4]` (supondo que se tratam de 4 variáveis diferentes de um exemplo/medida no tempo).

Comment: Enfim, ainda está confuso e eu não sei se entendi direito o que você precisa. Mas mesmo assim, estamos entrando em um domínio (time series) em que eu tenho pouquíssima experiência, não sei se consigo ajudar mais. Mas dá uma olhada neste artigo da documentação do Matlab, pode lhe ser útil: http://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/examples/time-series-regression-i-linear-models.html

Comment: P.S.: Me ocorreu agora que talvez você esteja chamando de "features" os valores da mesma variável ao longo do tempo. Se for isso, está errado. Você tem apenas uma feature, mas com vários valores ao longo do tempo (como no meu exemplo). Assim, seu `x` não deveria ser uma matriz, e sim um vetor (novamente, como no meu exemplo) e não faz sentido usar o valor atual como `y` porque ele não é uma "resposta", e sim mais um valor da sua massa de dados (ao menos no meu entendimento). Mas, enfim, novamente, não entendo muito de time series. Sugiro tentar perguntar lá no Math (que sugeri antes).

Comment: Você está certo quanto à parte das "features". Sim é só uma mas medida ao longo do tempo. Os dados dizem respeito à concentração de um ácido (só tenho esta informação) ao longo do tempo e eu preciso de saber a cada novo instante a concentração daí a N instantes (no futuro como é óbvio). Porque não posso  modelar isto em função dos valores passados da mesma variável? Porque é que `y` não pode ser 6? Seria a saída no instante `t+2` pressupondo que o valor 4 foi obtido no instante `t` ...
De qualquer forma vou ler a documentação que enviou a ver se percebo melhor isto.

Comment: Porque não é a mesma coisa. No exemplo que eu dei, o número de coelhos (o `y`) é um valor que é dado *em função* de outro (o ano, o `x`). Assim, não me parece que você pode usar "a mesma modelagem". Mas como eu disse, dai já estamos entrando em um domínio que eu não conheço. Posso estar enganado. Mas pra mim, não faz muito sentido (especialmente usando regressão). Boa sorte. :)

Answer (score 1):

Vou gerar uma variável aleatória RV para mostrar o procedimento. Para determinar o numero de defasagens tem que fazer alguns testes, pode procurar algum texto ou aqui no SO. Por exemplo [este](http://www.ead.fea.usp.br/semead/6semead/MQI/010MQI%20-Algumas%20Tecnicas%20para%20Anal%20de%20Series%20Temporais.doc)

```
%# Gerar uma variável aleatória autocorrelacionada em 3 períodos.
T = 1000;
%
RV = zeros(T, 1); RV(1)=10+randn(1); RV(2)=1.5+.8*RV(1)+randn(1);
RV(3)=1.5+.8*RV(1)-.3*RV(1)+randn(1);
for c = 4:T ; RV(c)=1.5+.8*RV(c-1)-.3*RV(c-2)+.25*RV(c-3)+randn(1); end

% Pode inicial aqui fazendo RV = SuaVariavel

plot(RV)

%# Construindo as variaveis com 3 defasagens
yout = RV(4:end); %# dependente
X1 = RV(3:end-1); %# defasagens da dependente (1er regressor)
X2 = RV(2:end-2);
X3 = RV(1:end-3);
%# matriz de regressores incluindo constante
X_train = [ones(length(X1), 1), X1, X2, X3];

%# MQO
mdl = regress(yout, X_train);
mdl

# Prever
X_test = [1, RV(T-1), RV(T-2), RV(T-3)];
%pred = predict(mdl,X_test);
sum(mdl'.*X_test) ; % Y em T+1
```

Comment: Obrigado desde já pelo exemplo. Eu fiz umas pequenas modificações ao código e gostaria de saber se a variável HP pode assumir valores maiores que 1 (ver EDIT1). Pelas experiências que fiz sim mas gostaria de ter a certeza.